# Does the View.Remove method clear the memory from the removed element?

Tags: xml, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Maybe this question can also be asked for remove methods of any other UI element not only for the View, but in my case i've removed an element(a View) from another View.

```
$.basewincontent.remove($.detailsoireescreen);
```

and this in order to optimimize my application memory. First, i want ask if the element is really removed from the memory, i've myself made some tests but coudn't know that , these are the tests code:

```
Ti.API.info("typeof $.detailsoireescreen : "+typeof $.detailsoireescreen);
Ti.API.info("test if $.detailsoireescreen is null : "+$.detailsoireescreen == null);
```

`typeof $.detailsoireescreen`

always returns

> "typeof $.detailsoireescreen : object"

in the console and `$.detailsoireescreen == null` always returns 0 
for this test, i was expecting the typeof to be "undefined" after the element has been removed and the boolean value to be 1(if that's the value returned by titanium for the boolean "true" instead of 0 (which is the false)

My second question is : as i'm working with Alloy and i'm writting my UI elements on the xml so then i'm not creating these element myself but they are read from the xml in the first time before i removed them. So after removing them as in my first question, can i load them again from the xml itself again ? or do i need to create everything as they never have been created ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you should worry about the javascript objects, but only about the real native UI components like the UIView you are trying to remove here. Removing it from the view hierarchy is sufficient for gaining back the memory it was occupying. You can verify that by tracing the available memory for your app using Ti.Platform.availableMemory before and after removing your view. For more details you can also try Instruments, the xcode tool for profiling.
2. You can reuse them as long as you do not nullify them after you remove them the 1st time, as you will lose then reference to them and they will be destroyed.